# Akka priority mailbox

Tags: akka

Imlemented a custom priority mailbox with classname "com.myshipments.mailbox". My use-case is to have separate actor for each items. The name of the actor for each item is of the item ShippingItem-* where * can be the item number.

I would like to assign the priority mailbox to all the ShippingItems actors. So in application.conf added the mailbox as:

```
shipping-item-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "com.myshipments.mailbox"
}
```

During the creation of the Akka Actor tried using

```
system.actorOf(   
Props.create(ShippingItemActor.class,itemId).withMailbox("shipping-item-mailbox"),"ShippingItem-"+ itemId);
```

**Problem**: The priority mailbox is never used. Tried to debug using eclipse but it never comes to the implemented class.

Comment: Observed when I pass a custom Object instead of String type, it is not invoking my custom mailbox priority generator. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Still not able to figure out the issue. The custom priority generator is active only when the a string message is sent. Hoping for some pointers from the experts.